# Error importing UnityEngine.Experimental.Director

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime

Today I was searching internet for Unity Runtime Level Editor and i found [GILES](https://github.com/procore3d/giles). I imported it and set *API Compatibility Level* to .NET 2.0, but I can´t solve this error:

```
Assets/GILES/Settings/pb_Config.cs(75,36): error CS0234: The type or namespace name Director does not exist in the namespace UnityEngine.Experimental. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

[image: screenshot]

This error appear in this piece of code:

```
typeof(UnityEngine.Experimental.Director.DirectorPlayer),
```

[Here is full source of this file on GitHub](https://github.com/procore3d/giles/blob/master/Assets/GILES/Settings/pb_Config.cs#L75).

I am using Unity version 2017.1.0f3. Is there any way to fix it? What I am missing?

**UPDATE:**
I searched in actual Unity documentation and it seems that `UnityEngine.Experimental.Director` was removed. Is there any alternative or way to use it in new Unity?

Comment: When you opened your project in 2017.1.0f3, did you get a dialog saying your scripts used obsolete APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is now UnityEngine.Playables.PlayableDirector